# Define Template in class private

Tags: c++, qt, templates

Im facing some trouble with defining a template var in class private scope

```
private:
template<class T>;
```

Im using visual c++ 2010 so what is wrong !!

Comment: perhaps you could tell us what type the private variable should be, what it should be called, and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I recommend reading a good book on c++

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you post minimum code which people can run on their compiler and see the error themselves

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the variable name.  Also you cannot declare a templated member variable like that, you have to templatise the class, and define the variable type using `T`.

```
template < class T >
class A
{
    T var;
};
```

Comment: i tried that and got the same error message :
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Comment: It works for me.  Can you post how you are trying to instantiate the class?

Comment: thanks  cmannett85 it's worked fine the problem was ; at the end of template defenation